# Store 2 ascii characters into 1 integer in C

Tags: c, string, ascii

I am currently working on a project involving ascii command strings for a display.  I have a string in my program (command string defined by a separate function) that I need to take apart and store into an array.  I need to store 2 ascii characters into each element of the array.  Here's my problem, the device is looking for ascii in HEX, my hardware will store the variables as decimal ascii.  So if I wanted to send the characters 'B' and 'A' to the first element, the display would expect to see 4241 in HEX, it would be 16961 in decimal rather than 6665.  If anyone has any suggestions, I would be extremely interested.  Thank you

Comment: This question is not very well defined. Do you have any code that you have tried? Its also hard to understand exactly what you mean by hex, do you mean as ascii hex strings? Or are they stored in binary, which can be represented as hex?

Comment: Paul R helped me out with this one.  I needed to produce an ascii hex string but I was stuck producing an ascii decimal string which does not work.  Paul suggested shifting and or'ing the characters.  I tried it this morning and it works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just combine the two `char`s using a shift and bitwise OR:

```
char ch1 = 'A', ch2 = 'B';
uint16_t buff = ch2 << 8 | ch1;  // buff = 0x4241 = 16961
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://ideone.com/nlBoQM)

---

Note on programming style: even though it's not necessary, some people prefer to add parentheses for clarity:

```
uint16_t buff = (ch2 << 8) | ch1;  // buff = 0x4241 = 16961
```

Comment: A pair of parentheses might make it clearer for people who don't know operator precedence by hearth ;)

Comment: @ddriver: normally I would, but my inner OCD self liked the fact that `ch2` lined up. ;-)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but shouldn't you cast `ch2` to a 16bit type before you shift it? Aren't chars in C 8bit, therefore losing the value by shifting 8 bits?

Comment: @user3735658: it's actually OK because of integer promotion rules, so no need to cast in this instance (although it wouldn't do any harm). Typically you only need to cast for bitwise operations when you're using types which are wider than an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, learned something new.

Comment: Paul R, I didn't even think about shifting! Thank you, this works perfectly.  I would upvote you if I weren't so new to the site.